# Issue while sending Header authentication in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Fetch Contacts

Do a GET request to http://ui-proj.practodev.in/contacts to obtain contacts.

To search a contact by name, email or phone pass search term as query parameter "q" e.g. http://ui-proj.practodev.in/contacts?q=test

API would return a HTTP 200 response with JSON of All Contacts available with key "contacts"

```
"contacts" : [{
   "id" : "1"
   "contact_name" : "Bob"
   "contact_phone" : "9876543210",
   "contact_email" : "bob@example.com"
}]

Here for fetching JSON data in client side my code so far;

$(document).ready(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:  'http://ui-proj.practodev.in/contacts',
            dataType: 'json',
   /*While accessing any of the urls from Contacts Demo API, 
   pass a header parameter X-USER with value as your email address to  authenticate.*/
   /*headers: {
    "X-USER" : 'bob@example.com"
   },*/
           beforeSend: function (request){
           request.setRequestHeader("Authority", authorizationToken);
           },
           success:function(data){
            $("#contacts").html(data);
           }
   });

});
```

Comment: If you run that in Chrome and press F12 then what's the error? My guess is that the same origin policy prevent you from accessing the api unless the code is from the same domain, subdomain, port and protocol. If you want to consume services from another server you should use JSONP on the server providing the service. Cors headers can be used but won't work with jQuery and IE.

Comment: The API supports Cross Domain requests using CORS and works on vanilla Ajax Requests (No need to implement JSONP Callbacks).

Answer (score 0):

I opened www.google.com in a browser (any of googles sites is fine as I'm in Cambodia I get redirected to google.com.kh)

Pressed F12 and pasted the following code in the console command line:

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

Clicked run (or press enter in Chrome)

Then pasted the following code in the commandline (console panel at the bottom)

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url:  'http://ui-proj.practodev.in/contacts',
    data: {q:"test"},
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function (request){
      console.log("beforesend",request.setRequestHeader);
      request.setRequestHeader("X-USER", "the.user.you.sent@email.com");
   },
   success:function(data){
    console.log("success",data);
   }
   }).done(function() {
     console.log("youre not trying",this);
});
```

When running that I get 404 user not found, I assume it would work when you sent known user credentials.

Comment: API docs is available will you plz give me your email id so i can forward you doc file in which written instructions.

Comment: Thanks. But what is var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(s);

Comment: @DevendraSingh The page at google.com doesn't have jQuery so that adds the jQuery library to the document `<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>`

Comment: Known user credentials are request.setRequestHeader("X-USER", "devsingh.mca@gmail.com");

Comment: @DevendraSingh Using the steps as described in my answer got me a successful ajax call.

Comment: I open google.com and clicked f12. pasted jQuery code in the console command line. Now i pasted ajax code but got an error, TypeError: Object function bound(var_args) { return func.apply(thisObject, args.concat(slice(arguments))); } has no method 'ajax'.
What ajax call you've got..?